# monitor two GPIO pins on PI

Tags: python

```
#import GPIO library
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#set GPIO numbering mode and define input pin
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.IN)
try:
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(16)==0:
            print "Open_16"
        else:
            print "Closed_16"

finally:
    #cleanup the GPIO pins before ending
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

how do i modify the above script to monitor 2 GPIO pins
16 is being monitored how to i monitor pin 16 and say pin 33

thanks for any help

Comment: Please ask this question on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please help me understand your question. Do you want to check the activity of pin GPIO(33)?
```if (GPIO.input(16) == 0) and (GPIO.input(33) == 0):```

Comment: hi i wanted to know if pin 33 was open or closed independently of the condition of pin 16

Comment: look at the answer from @ralf below.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import GPIO library
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

#set GPIO numbering mode and define input pin
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(33,GPIO.IN)
try:
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(16)==0:
            print "Open_16"
        else:
            print "Closed_16"

        if GPIO.input(33)==0:
            print "Open_33"
        else:
            print "Closed_33"

finally:
    #cleanup the GPIO pins before ending
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

If you want logical relations between the states of the two pins like AND, OR, XOR, ... use logical operators ( https://www.guru99.com/python-operators-complete-tutorial.html )